# Why do Enum operations fail when no type is given in GHCi?

Tags: haskell, enums, polymorphism

For example, I'd expect the following to simply use a default type, however:

```
 succ mempty
*** Exception: Prelude.Enum.().succ: bad argument
 succ minBound
*** Exception: Prelude.Enum.().succ: bad argument
 :t succ mempty
succ mempty :: (Monoid a, Enum a) => a
 :t succ minBound
succ minBound :: (Bounded a, Enum a) => a
```

I'd expect `(Bounded a, Enum a) => a` to at least match `Int`.

Comment: By using `mempty`, you add an extra argument: `Monoid`.

Comment: `Integer` is not `Bounded` and not a `Monoid`. In ghci types tend to default to `()` when not numeric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does “simply use a default type”, that's precisely the reason you get this behaviour!

Namely, defaulting tends to always use *the simple**st** type that matches the constraint*.

- When you're doing fractional arithmetic, you need `Double`<sup>†</sup>.
- When you're doing any other arithmetic, an integral type also does the trick; `Integer` is chosen which is simple in the sense of also having no bounds.
- Where there's no arithmetic, you don't need a `Num` type. Often, `()` is sufficient for fulfilling the constraints. Of course it may not be sufficient for fulfilling the *semantics* you intend, but that basically just means the inferred signature is more general then the one you would have wanted.

What I find slightly surprising is that GHCi won't default `(Num a, Bounded a, Enum a) => a` to `Int`, but gives up finding a default for `a`.

I generally avoid relying on defaulting at all. A good rule of thumb is to not make a function's arguments more polymorphic than the result<sup>‡</sup> (so the argument types can always be inferred from the context), and then if needed just add a single type annotation to the end of the expression at the REPL. This also works here, of course:

```
Prelude> succ minBound :: Int
-9223372036854775807
```

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Arguably, it would be more in line with the philosophy if the default `Fractional` type were `Rational`.</sub>

<sup>‡</sup><sub>Unless, of course, you have a particular reason. Conversion functions may need to be independently polymorphic in the argument and result, but they are usually only needed when there's *too much* type information around already which causes contradiction.</sub>

Comment: The "default `default`" is `(Integer, Double)`, then `ExtendedDefaultRules` expands that to `((), [], Integer, Double)`. This doesn't include `Int` -- which explains why GHCi won't default `(Num a, Bounded a, Enum a) => a` to `Int`. If you explicitly write a `default` declaration that includes `Int`, it will; e.g. try `default (Int)` and then `succ minBound + 1` in ghci.

Comment: Why is `()` in `Enum`, for that matter?

Comment: @MarkNeu because it is enumerable.

Comment: ...duh!... — ...seriously – the `Enum` class is a bit of a mess, so there's not too much I'd say about this. But, `()` is a trivial instance of a great many classes, and trivial instances are a good thing. Generally, instances are good if it's unambiguous how they behave, and for `()` it's completely clear that `minBound ≡ maxBound ≡ ()`. What's of course not nice is `succ _ = ⊥`, but this is a design problem of the `Enum` class itself and has little to do with the `()` instance in particular.